# Android SQLiteDatabase update error

Tags: android, sqlite

A piece of code to update DB raw:

```
private EditText et;
//...
private void updateRecipe(){
  SQLiteDatabase db=recipes.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(RECIPE, et.getText().toString());
  db.update(RECIPES_TABLE, values, "id=?", new String[]{id});
}
```

When ran, an error occures:

```
Error updating recipe=Efrerer using UPDATE recipes SET recipe=? WHERE id=?
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: id: , while compiling: UPDATE    recipes SET recipe=? WHERE id=?
```

These are my SQL queries:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+CATEGORY_TABLE+" ("+_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
              CATEGORY_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL);");    

      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+RECIPES_TABLE+" ("+_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
              RECIPE_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+CATEGORY_ID+" INTEGER, "+ RECIPE+" TEXT NOT NULL);");
  }
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+CATEGORY_TABLE);
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +RECIPES_TABLE);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, post statements you use to create db. It seems that you just don't create the appropriate column.

All you need is to check what value your _ID variable contains. May be it differs somehow from the desired 'id' you used in your update statement?

Comment: Thanks, that was total inattention.

Answer (score 1):

This error can be solved by just using `"id='" + <value> + "'"` as whereClause.
Droids SQLite API is quite capricious with strings and quotes..